# Is it possible to integrate Google Spreadsheet into a cloud application and store all app/user data on only one Google Drive account?

Tags: google-drive-api

Hi Google Drive SDK team on Stackoverflow. I need a personal reply from you guys as this question is important for the backend architecture of a cloud application we are working on.
We want to integrate Google Spreadsheet in the frontend of a cloud application, but we want to structure the backend in such a way that all
user application data/files is stored only on one main Google Drive and not in the user's Google Drive. Does the Google Drive SDK or other Google 
products enable the capabilityneed?  From the Google Drive SDK page the typical use case is that an app stores data in the user's own Google Drive account.
Our case is different and we want to store all data in our own Google Drive account. Looking forward to your reply. Thanks 
https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/copy#examples

Answer (score 0):

Its possible but you need to read more about how oauth works and spreadsheet permissions (btw im not from the drive team).
If you will use the users tokens your only option would be to have a backend create the spreadsheet on your drive (with you as the owner) and share it with the user.
If you will use your own tokens and not the user's, you will need a backend to serve as proxy for spreadsheet operations. That way you dont give write permission to the user (so she cant change your data). Drawback of using your own tokens is that you will have quota issues with many users.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do is decide which API you intend to use.

The link you posted is for the Drive API. This will allow you to upload and download spreadsheets, but **not** manipulate their contents.

If you require row or cell level access to a spreadsheet, that will use the Spreadsheets API. See https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/

Next decide how you will deal with permissions. You want a centrally owned spreadsheet, so you have three choices.

1. Proxy all of the access through a web server as suggested by @zig
2. Access the spreadsheet directly, but use a centrally provided access token
3. Use a Service Account